# Swift - Gomoku in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I've learned Swift for 2 months. I'm trying to rewrite Gomoku game in iOS. My game allows a player play with computer. I'm having a problem related to view. I'm having a custom UICollectionView.

There are a specified number of cells inside my UICollectionView. When the player interacts with a UICollectionViewCell, symbol "x" or "o" is shown up immediately, and they must wait for computer before their next turn. Below is my code.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let square = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Square
    if square.isEmpty(){
        // determine which player is available
        let curPlayer = game.isTurnPlayer1 ? game.player1 : game.player2
        if curPlayer is Human {
            //set symbol into each cell
            square.setSymbol(curPlayer.piece)

            // set move in board (model handling)
            {...}

            // computer will decide to move and change turn
            self.didMakeMove(indexPath, piece: curPlayer.piece)
        }
    }
}
```

Every time the player select a UICollectionViewCell (he makes a move), above method is called, I know view is updated if and only if that method is released, but I want view to show without waiting for completing method "didMakeMove".
I tried using dispatch_async in didMakeMove like that:

```
func didMakeMove(indexPath: NSIndexPath, piece: String) {
    //check if game is over
    {...}
    ////////// dispatch_async 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)){
        //calculate next move for computer
        {...}
    }
}
```

Then I run the game, I realize that the turn of computer is too slow to calculate. However, when I try replacing `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH` with `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, computer calculates its move faster. But sometimes, I have to wait until completing calculation to see both "x", "o" after I make a move.

Comment: _I know view is updated if and only if that method is released_ .. this is not clear to me atleast

Comment: I mean view will be updated if method collectionview with parameter didSelectedIndexPath is completed, otherwise, it won't.

Comment: i am not sure what your questions is here.. maybe try expalining it better

Comment: My question is how to make symbol "x", "o" (depends on who goes first) show immediately after player interact with a cell, then, no need to care about time for computer to calculate.

Comment: well you got chat rep.. [join](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow) and explain your problem. that would be good

Comment: When you dispatch to a background queue, make sure you go dispatch to the main queue for all UI updates. Otherwise, these changes to the UI will pop in at seemingly random times.